# Edit history like Stackoverflow itself

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement the Editing History functionality like this website itself which shows the initial post and how the edits were made.

Is there any specific name for this functionality and any source code available for it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: "diffing" would be my first search suggestion; google has some results for "text difference finder"

Comment: @MarcGravell Google brought no good results for this particular use case.